# replacing copyright symbol and other symbols with elements in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Input:

```
<text>
    Please see the registered mark® .
    Please see the copy right ©.
    Please see the Trade mark™.
</text>
```

Output:

```
  <text>
        Please see the registered mark<registeredTrademark></registeredTrademark>.
        Please see the copy right <copyright></copyright>.
        Please see the Trade mark <trademark></trademark>.
  </text>
```

I need to replace all special symbols with the elements as shown above

Can any one help.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do this with a simple text replace on the XML source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation is more efficient by avoiding char-by-char recursion and using "biggest-possible-step" recursion**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <my:reps>
  <r char="®">registeredTrademark</r>
  <r char="©">copyright</r>
  <r char="™">trademark</r>
 </my:reps>

 <xsl:variable name="vReps" select="document('')/*/my:reps/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="multReplace">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pReps" select="$vReps"/>

   <xsl:if test="$pText">
     <xsl:variable name="vTarget" select="$pReps[1]/@char"/>
       <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="not($vTarget)">
           <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:variable name="vReplacement" select="$pReps[1]"/>

           <xsl:call-template name="multReplace">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
            "substring-before(concat($pText, $vTarget), $vTarget)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pReps" select="$pReps[position() >1]"/>
           </xsl:call-template>

           <xsl:if test="contains($pText, $vTarget)">
             <xsl:element name="{$vReplacement}"/>
             <xsl:call-template name="multReplace">
              <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, $vTarget)"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pReps" select="$pReps"/>
             </xsl:call-template>
           </xsl:if>
         </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<text>
        Please see the registered mark® .
        Please see the copy right ©.
        Please see the Trade mark™.
</text>
```

**the correctly-replaced text is produced**:

```
    Please see the registered mark<registeredTrademark/> .
    Please see the copy right <copyright/>.
    Please see the Trade mark<trademark/>.
```

Comment: When my xml is having these special characters I am getting the error as "Invalid character in the given encoding". Is there any way to avoid it

Comment: @User222, You aren't saying what tool issues the error -- the XML parser, the XSLT processor or something else. So it is difficult to advise how to avoid such unidentified error. My guess is that somewhere (in code you haven't shown to us), you are specifying/using-a-default encoding, that doesn't have these characters. The solution is to specify utf-8 as the encoding (or not to specify anything if utf-8 is the default).

Comment: Thank you for the response. My Visual Studio is not supporting this.:(

Comment: @User222, I just copied and pasted the XML and XSLT into two VS windows and performed the transformation there -- without any problems !

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. There was some problem with my input xml. I rectified it. :)

Answer (score 2):

As this is XSLT 1.0, you are going to have to use a recursive named template to check each character in turn.

Firstly, it may be more flexible to create a sort of 'look-up' in your XSLT where you can specify a list of symbols and the required element name to replace them with

```
<lookup:codes>
  <code symbol="®">registeredTrademark</code>
  <code symbol="©">copyright</code>
  <code symbol="™">trademark</code>
</lookup:codes>
```

(The 'lookup' namespace could actually be named anything, just as long as it is declard in the XSLT).

Then, to access this, you could define a variable to access this look-up

```
<xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('')/*/lookup:codes"/>
```

And, to look-up an actually code based on a symbol would do something like this (where $text) is a variable that contains the text you are checking.

```
  <xsl:variable name="char" select="substring($text, 1, 1)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="code" select="$lookup/code[@symbol = $char]"/>
```

All the named template would do, is check the first character of the text, replacing it with an element if it exists in the lookup, and then recursively call the template with the remaining part of the text.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:lookup="lookup" exclude-result-prefixes="lookup">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

   <lookup:codes>
      <code symbol="®">registeredTrademark</code>
      <code symbol="©">copyright</code>
      <code symbol="™">trademark</code>
   </lookup:codes>

   <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('')/*/lookup:codes"/>

   <xsl:template match="text[text()]">
      <text>
         <xsl:call-template name="text"/>
      </text>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="text">
      <xsl:param name="text" select="text()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="char" select="substring($text, 1, 1)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="code" select="$lookup/code[@symbol = $char]"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$code"><xsl:element name="{$code}" /></xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$char"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:if test="string-length($text) &gt; 1">
         <xsl:call-template name="text">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, 2, string-length($text) - 1)"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<text> 
    Please see the registered mark<registeredTrademark /> . 
    Please see the copy right <copyright />. 
    Please see the Trade mark<trademark />. 
</text>
```